# Being $f(x,y)=e^{2x}+\sin(x+\ln(y+1))-1$, prove the existence of $g(x): ]-e,e[\to \mathbb R$ with $f(x,g(x))=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I have the function

$f(x,y)=e^{2x}+\sin(x+\ln(y+1))-1$

and I need to prove the existence of a function $g(x): \; ]-e,e[ \; \to \mathbb{R}$ with $e>0$ so $f(x,g(x))=0$ for all $x \in\;]-e,e[$ and calculate $g'(0)$.

I use the implicit function theorem to prove the existence of $y=g(x)$ around $(0,0)$ but I have doubts about being a function mapping $]-e,e[\; \to \mathbb{R}$. I found that the domain of $y$ is $]-1, \infty[$ because of the logarithm so wouldn't $g(x)$ be a function mapping $]-e,e[ \; \to \; ]-1, \infty[$ ?

Comment: Any function $f : A \to B$ can be extended to a function $\tilde f : A \to B'$ with $B' \supseteq B$ via $\tilde f(a) = f(a)$ for all $a \in A$.

Comment: Right, the notation $f : A \to B$ doesn't necessarily mean the value of $f$ can be every element of $B$, just that its values are within the set $B$. This is why we have other ways to describe when "the image of $f$ is $B$", "$f$ is surjective", etc.

Comment: Oh you're right. I understand now. Thank you so much for your help.